# a mathematical object that becomes zero when squared

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, matrices

1) is there a math object or number (any type; quaternion or its further generalization, for example) that becomes zero when some operation is applied to the object using itself? The object must not be zero.
also, when does such object not become zero when operated on it by another object?

2) is there an object that becomes zero when operated(multiplied) by another object?

3) is there any math object or matrix that satisfies the following property (I ask for the object that satisfies both constraints):

a)$ab+ba=0$ where a and b are math objects or matrices

b) $A^2=B^2$

for all objects I assume nonzero.

Comment: For (3a) this is a property called anticommutativity. The cross product of vectors is one example.

Comment: @Arthur edited.

Comment: See [zero divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor), [dual number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number)

Comment: @ttyy cross product of vectors still apply. If $ab + ba = 0$ for any $a, b$ from some specified algebraic structure, we have $aa + aa = 0$, thus as long as $2\neq 0$, any square is $0$ and therefore equal to any other square. So (3a) implies (3b) in most cases.

Comment: I'm fiddling with the question, whether the inverse of a certain infinite sized vandermondematrix is the Null-matrix. I could prove Nullity for some entries (assuming I've the correct formulae for the inverses of the LDU-factors). If you like you might look at http://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/InverseNullmatrix.pdf and possibly help me proceed (outside of this site)...

Answer (score 3):

There is some staff in quantum physics that works this way, but it is funnier just to create one from scratch.

Just use same approach as when we defined imaginary number $i$ as matrix

$$
i = \left(\begin{matrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

## $\theta$ is what we need

First we need to learn how to treat real numbers as matrices.
Lets suppose any real number is just it's real value multiplied by identity matrix, so

$$5 = \left(\begin{matrix}
5 & 0 \\
0 & 5
\end{matrix}\right)$$
This definition preserves all properties of real numbers.

Now we can try to find such matrix that
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{matrix}\right)^2 = \left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right) = 0$$

Now we just need to find solution to systems of equations.

I am skipping that part to results:

$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
a = -d \\
a^2 + bc=0
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
From here we can choose any solution we like and it will work.

I am choosing this:

$$
a = 1, b=1,c=-1,d=-1
$$
which equals to our desired matrix:

$$
\theta = 
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

You can square it to see that it is indeed squares to zero

And yeah, it is linear dependent matrix, which have zero determinant.

## But does it make sense?

To prove that this is legitimate definition of $\theta^2=0$ let's compute some staff that uses all real, imaginary and theta numbers.
P.S remember: $i^2 = -1$, $\theta^2=0$, $i \theta \ne \theta i$ - it is noncommutative (you can just multiply them and see).

Also consider following:
$$\theta i + i \theta = \left(\begin{matrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{matrix}\right) = 2$$
It is property that we get just by multiplying corresponding matrices and adding them.

Here is an example:
$$
3+2i+4\theta = 
\left(\begin{matrix}
3 & 0 \\
0 & 3
\end{matrix}\right)
+
\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & -2 \\
2 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)
+
\left(\begin{matrix}
4 & 4 \\
-4 & -4
\end{matrix}\right)
=
\left(\begin{matrix}
7 & 2 \\
-2 & -1
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

So by squaring that matrix we get:
$$
(3+2i+4\theta)^2=
\left(\begin{matrix}
45 & 12 \\
-12 & -3
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Now let's open squaring brackets manually, add matrices and see if it works.

$$(3+2i+4\theta)^2 = 5+12i+24\theta+8(i\theta+\theta i)=
\left(\begin{matrix}
5 & 0 \\
0 & 5
\end{matrix}\right)
+
\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & -12 \\
12 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)
+
\left(\begin{matrix}
24 & 24 \\
-24 & -24
\end{matrix}\right)
+
\left(\begin{matrix}
16 & 0 \\
0 & 16
\end{matrix}\right)
=
\left(\begin{matrix}
45 & 12 \\
-12 & -3
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

As you can see this number $\theta$ is good to go and good to use mathematical object.

## How to work with this super complex numbers?

You can do any operations on these super-complex numbers, such as raising a power, taking log, sin, cos, etc.

$$a+bi+c\theta$$

It generalizes to functions the same way you do with complex numbers - by eigendecomposition of resulting matrix.

See this cool dude full playlist on eigendecomposition, but this one video is most useful

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1loSrioE4Y

## I've got a matrix, I need these sick coefficients back from it. How?

If you done some calculations you may find that it is hard to get meaning back from these 2x2 matrix to coefficients for real, imaginary and theta numbers.

All we need to do is to solve(you know what) system of linear equations back from it.

For example we done some computing and we have a matrix

$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

To map it to coefficients we need to compute

$$
k_1 + k_2 i +k_3 \theta = A
$$

When you replace real, imaginary and theta with corresponding matrices, you will get yet another linear system, and I will skip all of this and give you solution:

$$
k_1 = \frac{a+d}{2}
$$
$$
k_2 = \frac{a-d}{2}-b
$$
$$
k_3 = \frac{a-d}{2}
$$

## That's it?

Yeah, you have just expanded your view on complex numbers and more powerful than previously!

Comment: Same way you can define $\mu ^2 = 1$ and it will have it's own set of properties... You know, you can do a lot of stuff in math, and if you feel like there is not enough numbers, just create some bro

Answer (score 2):

1. Is there such a quaternion: no. Since nonzero quaternions have inverses, $a^2=0$ would imply $a=0$, after both sides are multiplied by $a^{-1}$. But as for generalizations, rings in general provide plenty of examples. For instance, in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, you have $(2+4\mathbb{Z})^2=0+4\mathbb{Z}$. You can also do it with matrices: $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ squares to zero.
2. In quaternions, again no: if $ab=0$ for nonzero $a$ and $b$, multiplying both sides by $a^{-1}$ gives you $b=0$, a contradiction. But again, general rings provide thousands of examples. Both of the examples from item 1 work, for example.
3. As Arthur already noted in a comment, $ab=-ba$ is equivalent to your 3a, and we say that $a$ and $b$ "anticommute." He gave an example of a nonassociative algebra where that happens for many elements, but there are many associative algebras that do that too. I will give you a matrix example: $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\-3&-2\end{bmatrix}=-\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\-3&-2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$. For 3b in the case of the quaternions, I will let you try as an exercise that if $a^2=b^2$, then $a=\pm b$. Again for general rings it is not so easy, and there are as many examples as you want. For example, $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}^2$.